# Checking canDrop() result

Tags: react-dnd

I have a type of dragSource, let's call it `Card`, and a dropTarget `Stacks`. There are many stacks, but each card can't be dropped to all of them. So in the `Stack`'s `canDrop` method I get the `Card` being dragged, run some comparisons and return whether that card can be dropped.

So, all good until here. When a user tries dropping a `Card` to a wrong `Stack`, `canDrop` returns false and nothing happens.

My question now is, when the drop action fails, I want to display a message like "You can't drop this card here because of reasons". How do I do that using `react-dnd`? I can't use the result from `canDrop`, because the drop never happened so it isn't handled? I could move the `canDrop` logic to the function that moves the card to the desired `Stack`, but then `react-dnd` would only be specifying that a `Card` can be dropped on a `Stack` and all the logic for if a card can be dropped on a certain stack would be handled by my code.

Is this correct? Is there any other way of doing this using the library I'm not seeing? What would be a good approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the status of the finished drag (whether successful or not) via the DragSourceMonitor. You will still need to get clever/dirty over how to pass different reasons, I'm pretty sure hover is called even if cant drop, so could cache a reason when you drag over an incompatible drop target, then clear it when drag is complete...

```
const reasons = '';

const dragSourceSpec = {
  //... 

  endDrag: (props, monitor, component) => {
    if (!monitor.didDrop()) {
      console.warn('Drop could not be handled, because of: ', reasons)
    } else {
      console.info('Drop was handled, and returned: `, monitor.getDropResult())
    }
    // reset reason for next drag
    reasons = ''
  }

}

const dropTargetSpec = {
  //...

  hover: (props, monitor, component) => {
    reasons = monitor.canDrop() ? '' : 'Stack is full'
  }

}
```